# How to know number of workers for AWS m3.medium ngnix puma server?

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I am  using `Elastic Beanstalk` with `load balancer`(min 2 instances). The server instance is m3.medium. Server is `ngnix puma`. How to know **max of workers** and number of threads in those servers.